# using vuejs if radio button is selected, use dropdown to replace image found in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vuejs and I want to change the image that is currently showing on the page to whatever is selected from the menu. The array has a list of images and if the radio button is selected, then an image is selected, I want the url to update. I add :src but no luck what else is missing.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  imageNamesArr:['image1.jpg','dog.jpg','car.jpg'],
    todos: [
      
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>

  
   <select>
                <option v-for="img in imageNamesArr">{{img}}</option>
            </select><br>

                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                        <input id="radbad16" type="radio" name="gender">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11">
          
                        <img :src="imageNamesArr" alt="myimage" />
                        <p class="img-caption"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Enlarge Image + </a><br /><em>ghosted</em> by kitty carrieayll</p>
                        <p>some text can go here.</p>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your :src is taking in an array with all the image names. You should first retrieve the selected value and then use it as the source, instead of the entire array.

```
     data: {
          imageNamesArr:['image1.jpg','dog.jpg','car.jpg'],
          selectedImage: ''
          },
   
---
<select v-model="selectedImage">
    <option v-for="img in imageNamesArr"></option>
</select>
         <img :src="selectedImage" alt="myimage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

here src needs an exact name along with the directory path not an array of names. so you should based on your selection logic pick a name from the array and then bind it with src.

Something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>

  
   <select v-model="selectedOption">
                <option v-for="img in imageNamesArr">{{img}}</option>
            </select><br>

                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                        <input id="radbad16" type="radio" name="gender">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11">
          
                        <img :src="selectedOption" alt="myimage" />
                        <p class="img-caption"><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Enlarge Image + </a><br /><em>ghosted</em> by kitty carrieayll</p>
                        <p>some text can go here.</p>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <hr>
</div>
```

````
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  selectedOption: "",
  imageNamesArr:['image1.jpg','dog.jpg','car.jpg'],
    todos: [
      
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    },
   }
  }
})```
````